# Create database in firebase realtime database with unique database id

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create databases on the fly in Firebase realtime database.

I'm using the REST resources: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/database-management/rest/v1beta/projects.locations.instances/create

You have to parse a parm with the databaseId in a string.

When i'm trying to make a base64 string the database is not created. When I just parse some text it is, but what I really want is a unique id for the database where Firebase make it to awoid dublicates.

Anyone know have to create a database with a unique database id in Firebase realtime database?